# Creating a file from a jFileChooser component

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I am using `JFileChooser` as part of an export feature.  I would like for the user to be able to either select a file from `JFileChooser`'s file viewer or enter the name of a file in the filename text box.  From what I've read it's possible to get that value using the `getSelectedFile()` method, so I have some listeners that call `getSelectedFile()` and attempt to do some checks before executing the export.

The problem I'm encountering is that the `getSelectedFile()` method is returning null when I enter the name into the filename text box manually.  To add more confusion, the `getSelectedFile()` method does work in three different situations:

1. I populate it via `setSelectedFile()` (a user has clicked a value from a table and I use `setSelectedFile()`)
2. I click an existing file in the file viewer
3. I hit ENTER after populating the filename text box

I have three file filters but have had the same behavior regardless of if they are enabled or not.

Listeners that call `getSelectedFile()` are as follows:

- Event Listener for keyReleased
- Event Listener for mousePressed.
- PropertyChangeEvent listener on my jFileChooser
- Action Listener on my jFileChooser

Is there a better way to listen to my jFileChooser to get the user input?  I feel like I'm missing something very obvious ... any help is appreciated!

**edit**
A little more info ...

I have a `JFileChooser` component in a `JSplitPane`, which is in a `JFrame`.  I'm not calling `showOpenDialog` to get input from the user.  The component is accessible as part of the form.

What I would like to do is listen to the user input as he/she types.  I have a 'start export' button that I would like to leave disabled until the user has entered a valid filename in the filename textbox in the `JFileChooser` component.  To accomplish this I have a KeyEvent listener that I would like to use to get the filename as the user types it in.

**further edit**

Here is the action listener code:

```
jFileChooserExport.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jFileChooserExportActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

I also have a property change listener here:

```
jFileChooserExport.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
        public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            jFileChooserExportPropertyChange(evt);
        }
    });
```

Inside of both jFileChooserExportPropertyChange and jFileChooserExportActionPerformed I am trying to get the file the user has selected by invoking getSelectedFile().  In both cases, however, it remains null until the user does one of the three methods described above

Comment: FWIW I have spent most of today trying to get this to happen and tracked it down to a private JTextField with no way to access. Instead - I stuck the controls in a panel, called `fileChooser.setAccessory(controlPanel)`, and used `filechooser.showSaveDialog()` to display the form.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). The demo code there works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, I have read that tutorial (and their demo works for me as well) as I searched for an answer but I didn't see anything that addressed my specific problem.  I might have missed it though, can you show me where the tutorial would help?

Answer (score 0):

Since none of below seems to work, you might want to try to [add a PropertyChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#addPropertyChangeListener(java.beans.PropertyChangeListener)) to your JFileChooser, listening for the [SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY)

---

What might be possibly happening is that your file chooser may have [multi selection enabled](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#isMultiSelectionEnabled()), in which case [`getSelectedFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile()) will return null, but [`getSelectedFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFiles()) will return an array containing the selected file(s). You may either want to [disable multi selection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setMultiSelectionEnabled(boolean)), or use the array (If you want the user to only select one file, set multiSelectionEnabled to false).

Another possibility, though, is if you try to get the selected file but `fileChooser.showOpenDialog` or `fileChooser.showSaveDialog` were neither called yet or did not return `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`

Also, I believe JFileChooser is case-sensitive, so if the file name is "Foo.bar" and you enter "FoO.bar", it will think you want something else.

Comment: disabling multi selection had the same result.  I am not using showOpenDialog or showSaveDialog, let me try to call jFileExport.approveSelection() and handle that event ...

Comment: @dMoto hmm. Maybe we'll need a little more info about what you're attempting to do?

Comment: Right now I have added a propertyChangeListener that listens for PropertyChangeEvent.  This is not triggered, however, when the user types in the filename textbox.  I thought that maybe if I invoked approveSelection() it would trigger the property change event, but it doesn't seem to do that.